# Simulate Group SMS on Emulated Android Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I would like to be able to simulate group SMS threads on my emulated device.

I know you can send an SMS to the device via the extended controls like so:
[image: Send SMS to device from Number]

But this message comes from only the entered number and is not able to send to a group.

I have also learned you can have two emulated devices open at the same time and they can send and receive SMS between each other by texting (555)521-555x, where the last 4 digits are the number from the emulator name.

However, when three devices are open and I attempt to start a group SMS thread by texting (555)521-5554 and (555)521-5556 from third device, the message is not sent.

Is it possible to simulate a group SMS on a virtual Android device?